# I need a way to execute an array of ajax calls wrapped in a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise

The system I'm working with was designed to only make synchronous ajax calls, so i am looking for a workaround. First i have an ajax call that is wrapped in a function. I then wrap it in another function so it doesn't get executed when adding it to the array. So i have two arrays of async ajax call functions. I would like to execute everything in the first array, and then wait until everything has completed. I would then like to execute everything in a second array. This is what i have so far

I have a loop that goes through items and I have a wrap function for each item that takes in my already wrapped ajax call so that it doesn't get executed and stores it in an array like below

```
var postpromises = [];

var WrapFunction = function (fn, context, params) {
    return function () {
        fn.apply(context, params);
    };
}

var postPromise = WrapFunction(ajaxFunction, this, [{
    url: url,
    data: j,
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        //success
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //error
    }
}]);

postpromises.push(postPromise);
```

I then have the same code for validation. So before I move on to next page, I have the following

```
$.when.apply(undefined, postpromises).then(function () {
            console.log();
            $.when.apply(undefined, validatepromises).then(function () {
                console.log();
            });
        });
```

The issue is that when I get to the code above, none of my `postpromises` even get executed, so I feel like I may be missing something here.

Ideas?

Comment: WrapFunction dont return a promise

Comment: is that why the may not be executing?

Answer (score 1):

The function `$.when` require a promise, in your code you are returning a function that return nothing, so just return the result of the wrapped function:

- ES6 spread operator [REF](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- function *arguments* object [REF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```js
var postpromises = [];
var validatepromises = [];

function f1() {
  var fakePromise = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(() => {
    fakePromise.resolve("IM RESOLVED!!");
  }, 500);
  return fakePromise.promise();
}

//OLD ONE
/*var WrapFunction = function (fn, context, params) {
    return function () {
        fn.apply(context, params);
    };
}*/

var WrapFunction = function(fn, context, params) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(context, params);
  }();
}

var postPromise = WrapFunction(f1, this, []);
postpromises = [postPromise];

var validatePromise = WrapFunction(f1, this, []);
validatepromises = [validatePromise];

//OLD ONE
/*$.when.apply(undefined, postpromises).then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  $.when.apply(undefined, validatepromises).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
});*/

$.when.apply(null, [...postpromises, ...validatepromises]).then(function() {
  console.log([].slice.call(arguments))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good answer, but also improve on the unnecessary nesting of `$.when`. Instead return the value of the inner `$.when`, and apply the `then` on the outer promise chain.

Comment: Yes actually the nested `when` can be merged into one function, i ll update my answer